# How to Add Layers together in a residual network

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras, deep-residual-networks

```
# import the necessary packages
import keras
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, Input, Add
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Dense


class SmallerVGGNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes, finalact):

        X1 = Input(shape=(height, width, depth))

        # # CONV => RELU => POOL
        X = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(1, 1), name="con_layer1")(X1)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)
        X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1))(X)

        X = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(2, 2), name="con_layer2")(X)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)

        X = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(1, 1), name="con_layer3")(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)

        X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1))(X)

        # First component
        X0 = Conv2D(256, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
        X0 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X0)
        X0 = Activation("relu")(X0)

        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
        X = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(2, 2), name="con_layer4")(X0)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)

        X = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(1, 1), name="con_layer5")(X)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)

        X = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1))(X)

        # Second Component
        X0 = Conv2D(512, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
        X0 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X0)
        X0 = Activation("relu")(X0)

        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
        X = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(2, 2), name="con_layer6")(X0)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)

        X = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=(1, 1), name="con_layer7")(X)
        X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
        X = Activation("relu")(X)

        X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1))(X)

        # Third Component
        X0 = Conv2D(1024, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
        X0 = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X0)
        X0 = Dense(128, activation="relu")(X0)
        X0 = Activation("relu")(X0)

        X = Flatten()(X1)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)
        X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
        output = Dense(classes, activation=finalact)(X)

        model = Model(inputs=[X1], outputs=output)

        print(model.summary())
        return model
```

In the residual networks it should linked the normal layers with the residual or convolutional blocks. According to my code "X" are the normal layers and "X0" are the residual blocks. At the end i want to add these layers together. How to add these two layers together including a a relu activation function.

Comment: You asked basically the same question before, please put attention to your questions, specialy when people ask clarifications, you can always edit your own question, there is no need to create new ones.

Comment: Currently your X and X0 has different shapes, you'll have to add `1x1` convolution to match these dimension, then you can use `Add()` for skip connections.

Comment: @VivekMehta Can you add that and put the code

Comment: @roma972012 this question is closed as duplicate and will no longer accept new answers. Besides you should try it yourself and post a well researched [precise question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you are stuck at something.

Answer (score 0):

X0 is your residual block and X is your normal layer. First import  `from keras import layers`  then do  `layers.add([X,X0])`

Comment: The OP is trying to implement a residual block, your answer does not actually show how to implement that.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, Thanks,  I misunderstood the question, done.

Comment: @vkSinha i added that after that it says

Comment: ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38, 30, 128) (16, 12, 128)

Comment: @roma972012 In the residual block, you have two components your output and residual, they must have the same dimension.  So, either you have to match the output dimension to input or you have to do 1X1 convolution on the residual layer. Check this link : https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-residual-networks-9add4b664b03